# What are all these Apache Ignite exceptions at startup?

Tags: ignite

When I start the server I'm expecting to see evidence of my service starting up, but instead I get a lot of exceptions: https://gist.github.com/danellis/329be83700060f80563df33515551a7c

When it's activated, I connect my client and get this (which also confusingly contains pathnames from my client machine): https://gist.github.com/danellis/3e98a06cfca5afff43674c65a3fd2ddf

On the client I see: https://gist.github.com/danellis/8ec03a1b597f73ec767d5e0aad3fe1ee

I've tried this with the on-disk persistence deleted too.

Here's the configuration I'm using (generated by the web console): https://gist.github.com/danellis/6ff4a39f79ba438d29086a1c1ea57972

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue. There must be a Visor node connected to the topology. It causes these exceptions to appear.

It was fixed in [IGNITE-6863](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6863), so this problem should go away after you update to Ignite 2.4, which is expected to be out soon.

Comment: I don't have a Visor node connected. It's just a server, a web agent and a client.

Comment: GridGain web agent also causes these exception. Try disconnecting it, the exceptions should go away.